# Django javascript catalog view for i18n internationalization

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-views, django-i18n

I'm trying to get javascript_catalog for i18n working, no dice.

Followed the official guide [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/)

I get the following while running:

> ./manage.py makemessages -d djangojs -l fr_CA
>   --settings=settings.local

```
"CommandError: errors happened while running msguniq".
msguniq: error while opening "/webapps/.../djangojs.pot" for reading: No such file or directory
```

I have this in my project's urls.py

```
js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('project_name',),
}

urlpatterns += patterns('',
   (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
)
```

Added this is my base template:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog' %}"></script>
```

I have project_name in my INSTALLED_APPS as well.

I tried it from the package level as well as at the individual app level, creating the locale dir and putting the app in 'packages', ...etc. But the regular makemessages works just not the js catalog for the djangojs domain.

Please help.

Comment: Which version of Django you're running? Can you paste the value of LOCALE_PATHS

Comment: I'm using version 1.6 and the output of my LOCALE_PATHS is, "/webapps/project_name/locale" where I currently have my fr_CA translation, which does work, just not the js catalog.

Comment: Sorry neglected to mention that I also have my settings.py renamed to base.py and moved to "/webapps/project_name/settings", which also has a local.py that imports the aforementioned base.py.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I thought html files that included the 'script' js tag was also handled with the javascript catalog. In fact, from what I can tell only .js files get scanned. When I put

```
gettext('Text to translate');
```

in a .js file it worked. The error message above indicates that there was nothing to translate.

Comment: I suppose the correct way to translate html files is using the `{% trans %}` or `{% blocktrans %}` tags then, nice catch.